# How to debug visual studio 2017 generated C++ code .SO file and others third party libraries in android?

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, android-studio

I have my C++ library code in Visual studio and I am generating AAR format lib in android studio and using that in my android project.

aar format file built using multiple third party libraries. Is there any way to  debug in Android?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot debug Native C++ code as you could be used on Android Studio. The only way is to print logs to LogCat to see where the Code flows.

Comment: is there any way to get line number of .SO C++ build crash?. We are getting memory leak issue in C++ sometimes it's hard for us to find the exact threading memory leak because of the same function in class.

Comment: 99% of JVM crashes caused by a native code prints a big stacktrace in the Log. Native code is not interpreted so it's not possible to get a line number because the .SO is compiled for ARM/x86. You can get the method name and THE MEMORY OFFSET (it's write as "method +96") starting from THAT method's memory address, but it could be quite difficult to suppose a line number due to the compiler optimizations that could deeply change the code.